# AsyncLocal in WPF is null after first set on the same thread

Tags: .net, wpf

Help me understand this:

In my WPF (.NET 4.6.2) app I'm trying out AsyncLocal to handle login and set authenticated user on the thread. The issue boils down to this simplified code. In the Loaded event I set a default value on the main thread. In the button clicked handler I'd assume this default value to still be there, but it isn't. Now the AsyncLocal-value is gone and back to being null again. I have checked many times and the thread is always the same main thread with the same id. Why is this not working as I expected?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public static AsyncLocal<object> Test = new AsyncLocal<object>();

  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (Test.Value == null) // same main thread here as well
    {
      Test.Value = 2; // should not get here?
    }
  }

  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    Test.Value = 1; // get here on main thread
  }
}
```

Comment: This is something you can chase down when you use the AsyncLocal constructor that lets you use a Action callback.  Setting a breakpoint on your callback method let's you see that WPF does something fairly nasty when your app reaches Application.Run (after Loaded), it resets the thread's execution context.  And that makes you lose the value.  Pretty hard to give good advice here, "don't do it" is the only solid one.

Comment: I see. I can work with that. Add an answer if you want the points =)

Comment: Surely WPF programmers are much more interested in your "I can work with that" approach.  No real idea what you'd do.  Just post your own answer.

Comment: ouch ... didn't mean to offend you

Comment: None taken, just interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the execution context is cleared after the Loaded event. So I'm basically not trying to set the AsyncLocal before that point and expecting that to work now that I know that's not an option. Turned out I didn't really need that anyway, just wanted to know why it didn't work.